# Reliability of Security+ 2.0 versus Security+ LiftMaster Garage Door Opener

Tags: garage-door-opener, garage-door, interference

I have a circa 2001 Chamberlain LiftMaster garage door opener that randomly does not respond to wireless remotes (both car remotes and a wireless keypad). This morning I used the wireless keypad to close the door, then 20 minutes later tried to use the wireless keypad to open the door which failed. I then tried to use a wireless remote that was less than 6 ft from the opener and that also failed. 30 minutes later I left the house and was able to close the door from 60 or so feet away (as normal). I had similar issues last winter and no problems at all over the summer.

Because I had issues last winter, I purchased an [upgrade kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IPKPVCE) to try to alleviate these issues but only recently installed it. My understanding is that my old remotes will still be talking to the overhead opener unit but that I could possibly purchase a Security+ 2.0 remote that would talk to the wall unit. Is this how it works? Do Security+ 2.0 remotes handle interference better? Or would I be better off just buying a whole new opener system?

Admittedly this question is similar to this [existing one](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/53854/craftsman-garage-door-opener-works-intermittently) however, my question is would upgrading to Security +2.0 remotes be a good thing to try prior to replacing the opener.

Comment: Im not familiar with a Craftsman Liftmaster, but Liftmaster itself has amazing phone support.  Theyll answer questions about any age product, not just the current new install stuff.

Comment: Sorry, should have been Chamberlain LiftMaster (companies have merged now I think). Thanks, I'll give them a call

Comment: Call them. They will help with any age equipment.

Comment: In talking to an installer recently while he was replacing a garage door opener with a new Liftmaster unit, he said Liftmaster does not recommend using 120VAC LED lamps in their openers, as some of them generate radio interference that can severely reduce the range over which the remote control will work, or inhibit it entirely.  If the incandescent or CFL lamps in the original poster's unit were recently replaced with LEDs, it could explain the erratic behavior.

Comment: @andrew-p, thanks so much!  My wireless keypad recently recently stopped working well... I found it works great if I hold it right next to the opener, really poorly from its mount outside on the left of the door, and better (but not great) on the right side. Got nothing from pages of google results. Then found your post. Unscrewed the (recently installed) LED bulbs and the keypad immediately worked perfectly again. I was really confused what in the wall could be causing the interference; the light bulbs never occured to me. And I was about to order a new receiver board for $117. Thanks!